# TinyMCE- Formatting in paste

Tags: formatting, styles, tinymce, wysiwyg, paste

When we copy some content from any source and paste the content into the RTE :

I want to retain the default font style and font size of RTE.
The other styles can be pasted as-is from the source.

I have checked [paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste] property clears all the formatting like `<h1>` `<b>` etc.

Is there any other property?

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

```
paste_retain_style_properties
```

> This options allows you to specify which styles you want to retain
>   when pasting contents from MS Word and similar Office suite products.
>   This option can be set to a space separated list of CSS style names,
>   or "all" if you want all styles to be retained.

Add this paramter to your tinymce config anf it should keep those things:

```
paste_retain_style_properties: "font-size font-style"
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the settings will also need the `paste` plugin to be enabled.